# High current problem

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, diodes, inrush-current

I have this circuit:

[image]

I was asked to measure the inrush current for this circuit section.

One floating output actually goes to a microcontroller input and the other goes to an op-amp input terminal. While performing the inrush current test, I have disconnected the connection to the microcontroller and the op-amp.

I am using an electronic load to sink the 5mA at the cathode side of the diode. [Electronic Load](https://elektroautomatik.com/shop/en/products/programmable-dc-electronic-loads-br-conventional-and-regenerative/series-el-9000-t-br-conventional-electronic-loads-br-400w-up-to-600w/113/electronic-dc-load-0...200v/0...18a)

This is what I observed:

[image]

The maximum current through the diode is 6.80A for a time duration of around 10us.

I am unable to understand how there can be such a huge current through the diode D0001 even though it is for a small duration. Please check the input voltage rise time also.

What is the reason behind such high current through the diode D0001?

Comment: Probably C0012/C0013 charging. Quick LTSpice simulation with KEMET X5R capacitors and 100ns rise time shows a spike of 7.2A (theoretically).

Comment: Could you please explain me why this is happening?

Comment: $$I = C\cdot\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

Comment: But I am getting like, I = 23.5nF * (32V/3us) = 250mA.

Comment: Zoom in on the input voltage step. We can't tell from the current picture but it's probably rising much faster.

Comment: The scope measurement says the rise time of the Input voltage is 3us.

Comment: So, basically, the huge current is due to the formula, I = C(dv/dt) only? That's all?

Comment: Maybe the electronic load has an input capacitance that adds to your circuit capacitance of 23.5 nF? Try testing the electronic load independently to your actual circuit. Then try testing your circuit with the load disconnected.

Comment: Sure thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

\$ Q = i.t \$

6.8A during 10µs gives Q = 68 µC ; since the pulse has nonzero rise and fall times it's probably less than that, let's say 30-60 µC of charge has circulated.

\$ Q = CV \$

Total input capacitance is 47nF, which requires 1.5µC to charge to 32V.

**Where have the extra µC gone then?** The scope shot gives some clues. I've zoomed it, it would be better if you measured it with a faster horizontal sweep, but that will do.

[image]

Of note, the input voltage goes up very quickly, which means the first pair of capacitors before the diode charges very quickly. Then, the inrush current spike keeps going long after that.

One hypothesis could be: the electronic load has an input cap. The current pulse has a really nice exponential decay, that could be a cap inside the load charging, with current decay due to its ESR, but... that feels wrong, because the shape of the curves don't fit that scenario.

What I think is happening is your electronic load probably has an opamp driving a FET with a source resistor, acting as a current sink like this:

[image]

And before the power supply is connected, the load tries to draw the set 5mA but it can't, so the opamp is clipped. When the power supply is applied, the opamp will take a while to wake up, get out of clipping, get into slew rate limit etc, and during that time the FET is still fully turned on which means the electronic load acts like a low value resistor, allowing a huge current spike. Then the opamp output will finally converge to the proper voltage on the MOSFET gate to get the desired current. This would explain the scope shot nicely, including the exponential decay.

So what I think you're doing is, you're testing the transient behavior of your electronic load.

This hypothesis can be tested easily, by measuring the inrush current of the electronic load alone, leaving your circuit out of the picture. I bet you're going to find the exact same spike.

While you're at it, you could also test the transient behavior of the power supply, by using a MOSFET to quickly switch a resistive load, see if the output voltage drops or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me, what purpose does an Op-amp present inside an Electronic Load, serve? Just for understanding purpose I am asking.

Comment: This is just a guess, but usually these loads are implemented as a controlled current source, built as the schematic above. There would be other circuitry of course, a microcontroller, DAC to set the current, etc. Using an opamp provides low offset and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

By theory if the 32 V source has no resistance then the inrush current is infinite. This is true for both C8 and C9 (and also C12 and C13 if the resistance of the diode is 0).  If you know the source resistance R of the 32V then the initial inrush is 32/R.  You can work backwards from your graph and determine R from the current peak. R=E/I =32/6.8= 4.7 ohms. That is the simple theory.
In reality there are numerous undrawn elements like the inductance of the wires that give a finite rise time and smooth curve.

Comment: If the 32 V source has no resistance *and infinite slew rate*; don't forget that one.

Comment: But in my case, the inrush current depends only on the capacitors, right? Assuming I am using a Lab bench power supply for the Input Voltage. https://elektroautomatik.com/shop/en/products/programmable-dc-laboratory-power-supplies/dc-laboratory-power-supplies/series-psi-9000-t-br-320w-up-to-1.5kw/511/lab-power-supply-0...200v/0...15a - This is the bench power supply that I used.